# Deform points in a plane

Tags: math, opencv, transformation, polygons, roi

Point :: (x y)  is known.

I have points inside a triangular region.
I know the coordinates of the vertices in initial and final positions. I know the initial coordinates of all the points inside the triangular region.

Now **I want to find out the final coordinates of all the points inside the triangular region.**

The picture below shows the points in initial and final positions.

[image] [image]

Can anyone tell me how to do this in OpenCV and C++ platform??

Can I do this for arbitary shaped contour also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using 3D coordinates to take account

- translation by vector `[u v]`
- 2D linear transformation made by matrixabcd

The overall transformation matrix will have the form

```
    [ a b u]
M = [ c d v]
    [ 0 0 1]
```

1. Take 3 points `A=[x1 y1 1]` and `B=[x2 y2 1]` and `C=[x3 y3 1]` from the triangle
2. Compare them with their position after transformation `A' = [x1' y1' 1]` and `B'=[x2' y2' 1]` and `C'=[x3' y3' 1]`. Id est: Do your math to get the transformation matrix `M`  so that `A' = M A` and `B' = M B` and `C' = M C`
3. Apply `x -> M x` to every input points

Edit: Incorporate the translation in the matrix `M` using [Translation in transformation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_matrix)

Edit: It seems "do your math" is not clear for you.

You'll realize that the 3 equations can be written as:

```
[x1' x2' x3']     [x1 x2 x3]
[y1' y2' y3'] = M [y1 y2 y3]
[1   1   1  ]     [1  1  1 ]
```

or

```
X' = M X
```

Or

```
M = X . X'^-1
```

and yes, OpenCV has a function `inv()` on matrices.

Comment: Now I have 6 unknow variables (4 in `M` and 2 in `T`) and 6 equations (2 for each transformation * 3 transformations). Eveything sounds good :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit :: Can you also refer me how to solve the equations using OpenCV...

Comment: @2vision2 What's your question when applying this to `CvMat` and `CvPoint` ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you... I will repeat my question..." I have 6 variables and 6 equations to solve.. How do I do this in OpenCV?? Is there any function to do this?? "

Comment: There is a `cv::solve()` which explicitly does what you want.  You can also use `Mat::inv()`, which uses the same mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, you can do this by computing the barycentric coordinates of each point in the original triangle, and converting back to position using the new coordinates:

```
given initial triangle vertices A, B, and C, and point p,
find barycentric coordinates (a,b,c) such that a+b+c=1 and p = a*A + b*B + c*C:
  -> solve  [A.x B.x C.x]   [a]     [p.x]
            [A.y B.y C.y] * [b]  =  [p.y]
            [ 1   1   1 ]   [c]     [ 1 ]

then, given new vertices D, E, and F,
resulting point q = a*D + b*E + c*F:
  -> compute  [q.x]  =  [D.x E.x F.x] * [a]
              [q.y]     [D.y E.y F.y]   [b]
                                        [c]
```

So, in OpenCV:

```
float p_data[3] =
  { p.x,
    p.y,
    1.0
  };
Mat_<float> p(3, 1, p_data);

float m_data[9] =
  { A.x, B.x, C.x,
    A.y, B.y, C.y,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0
  };
Mat_<float> M(3, 3, m_data);

Mat_<float> bary(3,1);
cv::solve(M, p, bary, DECOMP_LU);

float n_data[6] =
  { D.x, E.x, F.x,
    D.y, E.y, F.y
  };
Mat_<float> N(2, 3, n_data);

Mat_<float> result(2,1) = N * bary;
```

To map `point_count` points at the same time, set the number of columns of `p`, `bary`, and `result` to `point_count` instead of `1` (while increasing the size of `p_data` accordingly, etc.)

Depending on the application, it may be more convenient/efficient to explicitly compute the affine matrix first, and apply it directiy:

```
Mat_<float> Affine = N * M.inv();
Mat_<float> result = Affine * p;
```